# Why does Visual Studio Code show User Settings instead of running a PHP file?

Tags: php, configuration, visual-studio-code

I noticed that in Visual Studio Code there is a menu item called *"Start Without Debugging"* under the *"Debug"* menu. When I have a PHP file open, I expected this to run the PHP file through the PHP executable and give me the output. Instead, when I click on *"Start Without Debugging"*, the User Settings page shows up. Why does the User Settings page show up? It's not clear why this page is presented to me. Does it want me to configure something? How do I get it to just run the PHP file that I have open through the PHP executable. Is this even possible?

I noticed in the Default Settings there is a property called `"php.validate.executablePath"` that is set to `null`. I tried overriding this setting in my User Settings by pointing it to the path of my PHP executable like this:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
}
```

But that didn't solve anything. The User Settings page still shows up when I click *"Start Without Debugging"*.

Comment: Which extension are you using for debugging? Maybe that extension does not support the *run action* as mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode).

Comment: @HaaLeo I only installed the PHP extension that Visual Studio Code suggested I install when I started a PHP project.

Comment: @HaaLeo So do I need to install a PHP extension to support it? It's weird that they have that menu option there and when I click it, it opens the User Settings page. I don't get why it does that. Seems like a bug.

Comment: So I guess you installed [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug)? Have you followed the installation guide and set up a `launch.json` file?

Comment: @HaaLeo That seems superfluous to what I want to do. I just want to run the file. That's what I thought Run **Without** Debugging would do. I don't need to step through the code or set breakpoints which is what I think xdebug would allow me to do.

Comment: Due to the fact it is not working so far I would give it a try. Even the extensions descriptions points out it can be ["run without debugging"](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug#features).

Comment: @HaaLeo Thanks for your help. I found out that I don't need to install xdebug or the PHP extension. I found [this section in the vscode doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18401#issuecomment-272400316) comment that mentions creating a global launch configuration. I just had to put this `launch` object in my User Settings with `runtimeExecutable` pointing to my PHP executable. After I did that, it executed the PHP file when I pressed Ctrl+F5 and displayed the output in the debug panel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing more research, I found the solution to my problem. Based on [this section in the vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration) and [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18401#issuecomment-272400316) that mentions creating a global launch configuration, all you have to do is add a `launch` object to your User Settings JSON.

In my case, I added this to my User Settings:

```
"launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${file}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your value for `runtimeExecutable` may be different depending on the path to your PHP executable.

Comment: I just realized this solution was already posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868021/is-it-possible-to-have-a-global-launch-json-file. Hopefully my answer helps someone who needs the PHP configuration.

Comment: I ran into this same issue trying to run a C++ file. It's mind blowing to me that this is the expected solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same issue except I was trying to run a C++ file (doing all this in Windows 11). I followed the [instructions here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc), which said that I needed to run VSCode from within a "developer terminal" (which is able to run cl, the command for the MSVC C++ compiler).

At first, I did so and it still did not work (I'm absolutely sure of this). But then I tried again and it worked; I was able to run and debug a hello.cpp. Not exactly sure what happened, maybe it needed time to "warm up" or something (which would be awful if true).