# How to enable Java assertions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, assertion

When running a Java program from the command line, assertions can be enabled with the `-enableassertions` option for the `java` command. Running this program would then (and only then) fail with an `AssertionError`:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        foo(2);
    }

    private static void foo(int x) {
        assert x > 5;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

How can this be done when running a Java program in Visual Studio Code with the *Java Extension Pack*?

Answer (score 21):

Visual Studio Code manages launch configurations in the `launch.json` file in the project folder root.

The `-enableassertions` option can be added there with the `vmArgs` key like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "My App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "App",
            "projectName": "my-app",
            "vmArgs": "-enableassertions"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. But this will require add the line to every single file, I'm wondering if there is a way to add to some "global" config, so every file can be applied.

Comment: @CharlesC seems like it is possible to have a global `launch.json`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36868021/1225882

Comment: leave the name, mainclass and projectname empty(:"",), and it'll only launch with active or open classes