# How to change default launch settings in VS Code Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the "Launch Chrome against local host" option in my debugger list in VS Code. Definitely don't remember how I got it, but, I use it, and it's great. But every time I start it, it opens up the launch.json for setup, with the url set to `localhost:8080`.

These days I'm using it with React, so I always have to change it to `localhost:3000`.

I see that the launch file is located in a .vscode folder but that appears to be created anew in each project once I start the debugger?

Where do I set the "default" configuration(s) for the Chrome debugger setup so it always loads the same? I'm on a Mac, if that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a global launch.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868021/is-it-possible-to-have-a-global-launch-json-file)

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation you can add in the `settings.json` (the global one) a `launch` argument with default configurations/compounds that you can run from all of your projects.

see https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/

For example

```
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
           {
            "name": "Python: DEFAULT Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "autoReload": {"enable": true},
            "justMyCode": false
          }
        ],
    "compounds": []
    }
```

This will add a `Python: DEFAULT Current File` configuration to all of your projects.

I've tried setting a specific option (and not a configuration) and it didn't work, but I think setting a global configuration is a good solution for your problem

Comment: Does it work for task.json as well?

Comment: the link <https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/> is now broken.
The official docs can be found at [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to go about this is to simply locate your file folder and delete the `launch.js` file or delete the `.vscode` folder. This should return your launcher settings to default.

Answer (score -3):

[Jonathan Tuzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6826164/jonathan-tuzman) for setting up a terminal you can refer to the [following doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) or additionally you can edit the **settings.json** file and adding the following command:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

The simplest way to reset VS Code back to the default settings is to clear your user settings.json file contents which is found in Settings editor. You can navigate to Settings editor by **File > Preferences > Settings** and clicking on **Edit in settings.json**. For more information on this topic please refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_how-can-i-reset-my-user-settings)

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I am not trying to set up a terminal, nor am I trying to reset a default, but rather trying to set a default. I have looked through the settings.json file but couldn't find anything that seemed relevant. Also I'm on a Mac.