# How to automatically run python files using python -m in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need to run files using `python -m foo.bar.baz` due to having absolute imports in other areas of the codebase.

In VS Code, when I click the top-right corner to `Run Python File`, I'd like it to automatically do `python -m foo.bar.baz` instead of `python /absolute/path/to/foo/bar/baz.py`. Is this possible?

Of course, this should work automatically for any file regardless of where it is, not just for `baz.py`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173013/how-to-change-default-launch-settings-in-vs-code-debugger) suggests modifying `settings.json` but they don't provide an explicit example for how to do it exactly like this.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786022/shortcut-for-running-terminal-command-in-vs-code

Comment: @Sergio2405 that might be helpful but it's not a complete answer. How do I ensure is uses the correct path to the file separated by dots and not slashes? Is there a built-in variable for that?

Comment: look at the options of the python launch config

Comment: @rioV8 I've tried that but couldn't figure it out. Could you post an answer filling in the correct info?

Comment: This isn't possible in the general case: Whether `python -m` is available for a given piece of code depends on `sys.path` and where it is relative to any entries in same. Some .py files won't be located at a valid (`import`able) module location at all. One can try to heuristically guess, or set up a shim that adjusts PYTHONPATH, but getting that guess wrong will have messy side effects, so I don't advise the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

> when I click the top-right corner to Run Python File, I'd like it to automatically do `python -m foo.bar.baz` instead of `python /absolute/path/to/foo/bar/baz.py`

I don't think this is possible at the time of this writing.

The settings relating to running the active Python file in the terminal start with `python.terminal.`. I don't see any such settings to get exactly what you want.

For the part of just passing arguments to the Python interpreter, use the `"python.terminal.launchArgs": []` setting in your settings.json file and fill the array with [commandline argument](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) strings.

The setting's description:

> Python launch arguments to use when executing a file in the terminal.

Ex.

```json
python.terminal.launchArgs": ["-m"]
```