How to use different vscode `launch.json` settings for Debug (F5) and Run (CRTL+F5)?
I have a Python Tool, which I call with some (use case depended) arguments and which is still under development.
In my launch.json I have:
{
    "name" : "Project-ID XXX: Some name",
    "type" : "debugpy",
    "program" : "path_to_my/python_tool.py",
    "args" : [
        "--some-property", "argument",
        "--another-property", "lalala",
        "--this-list-goes", "On and On and On..."
    ],
    "env": {
        "PYTHONOPTIMIZE": "0"
    }
}

If I'm done developing and want to run the full program I change PYTHONOPTIMIZE to 1 and run it with CRTL+F5.
Can I somehow tell vscode to use PYTHONOPTIMIZE=0 when debugging (F5) and PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 when running (CRTL+F5) the program?
I've looked through the documentation of vscode and didn't find anything suiting.
Is there maybe another common way to solve my problem? After all the -O, or PYTHONOPTIMIZE option sets the internal __debug__ variable to False when given, so I belive there must be som vscode way to set it within the launch.json.

loosely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77471469/11107541

At the moment it doesn't seem to be possible to fulfill your request directly, you can configure a different configurations and then select it in the debug panel. I filed a report here you can follow up.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23183

As far as I know, VS Code itself doesn't have any features that would support this in a very DRY way. launch configs do not have shared properties or inheritance, and variable syntax does not have conditionals. I'm also not aware of there being a variable for whether the current launch config is being launch with or without debugging.
You have the option to write almost the same launch config twice- one for debug, and one for running without debugging. The debugpy extension (which contributes the debugpy launch config type) has a launch config property noDebug that you can use to make one of the launch configs be for running without debugging. Other launch config types support the "Run Without Debugging" action (available in command palette and in "Run" menu).
If you want something better, you'd need to raise an issue ticket(s) in the VS Code repo, describing your use case and maybe proposing a solution.
