# VS Code explorer (terminal) kind resets every time for new projects to 'integrated'

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, vscode-debugger, msvc12, cl.exe

Whenever I create new project in VS Code using Developer Command Prompt, workspace explorer kind (terminal) is being set to integrated, even though it's external in overall user settings.

[Worspace settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/735ON.png)
[User settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZGsK.png)
[`settings.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld1Du.png)

First of all, it's already weird that it's being set to integrated even though it's external in user settings and it should have followed what's in user settings in the first place when you create a brand new project unless I change it myself after creating the project.

However it doesn't end here. Even if I manually change the setting in workspace to external and build program using MSVC compiler (cl.exe) it is still being opened in integrated terminal like nothing changed. Even if I create "setting.json" inside my project and manually type      `"terminal.explorerKind": "external"`    it doesn't work.

[Program runs in the integrated terminal despite the setting being changed to external](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbsyE.png)

The only way around is by adding debug configuration and there changing console to     `"externalTerminal"`    in launch.json.

[`launch.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HagbD.png)

So it seems like the problem lies in cl.exe, MSVC or Developer Command Prompt that sets default value to integrated terminal.

I don't mind integrated terminal and even want it more than external one, but the behaviour seems very strange to me.

I was tweaking this setting in the past and now tried to get back to external terminal and it turned out unsuccesful as you see with only possible solution being to overwrite the `launch.json` inside the project, which bothers me a lot.

I suspect I have to change default launch configuration of cl.exe, but how to do that?

Comment: did you open the folder as a root workspace in a multi-root workspace? or did you open the parent folder of your desired workspace folder as the actual workspace folder? because it looks like either of those is the case.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But I created a brand new folder and project. I opened up Developer Command Prompt, there created a new folder and then typed "code .", after which VS Code started with opened folder I already created and there I created 'main.cpp', typed the code and built the project. @starball

Comment: then why do you already have a .vscode folder there? are any of your other workspace-scoped settings actually taking effect?

Comment: Oh, no no. It is created after I build the project. And launch.json and settings.json were created manually by me afterwards. So, first I build the project, the tasks.json is created, it then runs in integrated terminal. I created settings.json, typed "terminal.explorerKind": "external" and there is no use, then I created launch.json, changed 'console' field to "externalTerminal" and only now it opens up in external terminal as I wanted. I created settings.json to show that it doesn't solve the problem and tasks.json was created during the build. @starball

Comment: What about other workspace settings, I have jut tried changing "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle" to "line" and after saving, it immediately changes, don't even have to build and run the program. @starball

Comment: so when you right click a file in VS Code's explorer view, the context menu actions says "open in integrated terminal" instead of "open in external terminal"?

Comment: Strangely enough it says "Open in External Terminal", even though if I build and run the project it will run in integrated terminal. To change it I typed "terminal.explorerKind": "integrated" in setttings.json and only after that context menu changed to "Open in Integrated Terminal". @starball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even if I create "setting.json" inside my project and manually type "terminal.explorerKind": "external" it doesn't work.

> The only way around is by adding debug configuration and there changing console to "externalTerminal" in launch.json.

That's not a "way around". That's ***the** correct way* to do to get what you want for launching a C or C++ program using the cppvsdebug launch config type.

`"terminal.explorerKind": "external"` doesn't apply to cppvsdebug-type launch configs. That's just not what it does. Read its description (emphasis added):

> When opening a file **from the Explorer** in a terminal, determines what kind of terminal will be launched
>
> `external`: Use the configured external terminal.

I'm not aware of a way to change defaults for extension contributed launch configuration types. [You can, however, define launch configurations globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472612/11107541), and use their `group > isDefault` property with a glob pattern to define it as a global default for files of that extension (see [this post](/a/77652228/11107541) for an example of the default glob thing).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your explanation. And how do I change cppvsdbg launch default config so it's external again? It changed to 'integrated' and now I have to always manually create launch.json and there specify the 'console' field. It was external by default before.

Comment: Thank you! Now I better understand what the "explorer kind" setting means and also I've managed to setup a default launch configuration and global task.json, which is incredible and works just fine.

Still, I don't understand why does the workspace setting for explorer kind is set to 'integrated' every time I create new project and despite it works like it's 'external'? Is it bug or something?

Comment: Also, you've mentioned "group > isDefault" property regarding launch configuration, but there seem to be no such property. Did you mean it for tasks? Regardless, what does it actually do, and do I really need it? If "isDefault" set to true it still works fine and globally I think? When it's in User's tasks.json.