# Should you commit .vscode/symbols file to source control?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code

[This popular answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32979933/11236) says you should commit the entire `.vscode` folder into source control ... so one of my team members did just that.

However, I'm now finding that a file `.vscode/symbols.json` is destined to be committed. This file is a huge one-line json file, and I forsee impossible merge conflicts if I commit it.

What's the take on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

gitignore.io recommends [ignoring everything but a few files](https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudiocode):

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudiocode

### VisualStudioCode ###
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudiocode
```

[Joe](https://github.com/karan/joe) gives the same recommendation (I think both tools take their ignores [from GitHub's gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/VisualStudioCode.gitignore)). I think it's safe to say that `.vscode/symbols.json` shouldn't be committed.