# What is a .vscode file in Github?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have pulled cloned a project on Github and get an `.vscode` file with an empty `settings.json`

Is it recommended to keep it?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `.vscode` *directory*? As long as `settings.json` inside is empty, it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: Github is a red herring. You could have received these files by fax or messenger pigeon and the folder would still be there.

Comment: There's only one line with 2 numbers (123,125)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I commit the .vscode folder to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964920/should-i-commit-the-vscode-folder-to-source-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.vscode` is a folder which contains vscode workspace settings as well as configurations.
To know more about vscode workspace you can go there : `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces`

If you want to use that github user's particular workspace settings you can keep it. It's a good practice to maintain workspace settings.