# How "Run-Script" works in VS Code for node.js applications when debugging?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

[image: screen]

I added a config `start:debug` manually but then again VS Code shows another one as well. Both executes the application but when I run mine it does not show all the app console outputs in terminal e.g. errors, logs, etc. but when I run VS Code's one then everything works perfectly and I prefer to the use that config across our team.

Problem is I cant checkin the config so in another machine it does not show up as expected. How does VS Code get that config and execute it? If I can replicate that in my config then I can check it in my repo for others to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the steps to solve your mystery: by following along, you'll both discover the task configuration settings for the elusive option, and discover how it was added to your list:

1. Create an empty folder (I named mine `so-70196209` after this question ID), and open it in a new VS Code workspace.
2. Create a `package.json` file in the folder. Make sure it has a `start:debug` script entry like this:

   `package.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "so-70196209",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "start:debug": "echo \"Success\"",
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "MIT"
   }
   ```
3. In the VS Code menu, select "Run" > "Add Configuration..."

   [image: run > add configuration]
4. In the list that appears, select "Node.js":

   [image: node.js]

   A file at `.vscode/launch.json` will be created with a default task like this:

   `.vscode/launch.json`:

   ```
   {
     // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
     // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "type": "pwa-node",
         "request": "launch",
         "name": "Launch Program",
         "skipFiles": [
           "<node_internals>/**"
         ],
         "program": "${file}"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   > You can delete this default task later if you don't want to keep it, but just leave it for now and follow along to the end.
5. Select the "Run and Debug" icon in the [Activity Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface).
6. In the "Run and Debug" Side Bar, select the dropdown menu and choose "Node.js...":

   [image: node.js]
7. In the list that appears, find the entry with the text "Run Script: start:debug". Find the **gear icon** on the right, and **select the gear**.

   > If you hover over the gear, a tooltip will appear with the text "Edit Debug Configuration in launch.json"

   [image: run script: start:debug]

   This will add a new entry to `.vscode/launch.json`, and this entry is the one that you've been searching for. (The reason why it wasn't in your launch config, but was in your dropdown list, is because you previously clicked the entry line at some point, but not the gear. I don't know why this adds it to the dropdown and not the config, but that's how it works right now.)

   The config file now looks like this:

   `.vscode/launch.json`:

   ```
   {
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "type": "pwa-node",
         "request": "launch",
         "name": "Launch Program",
         "skipFiles": [
           "<node_internals>/**"
         ],
         "program": "${file}"
       },
       {
         "type": "node-terminal",
         "name": "Run Script: start:debug",
         "request": "launch",
         "command": "npm run start:debug",
         "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   The "Run and Debug" dropdown menu now has the entry you want:

   [image: run and debug dropdown menu]

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly commit your `.vscode` folder as suggested by a [VS code developer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32979933) and a [video on it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8p7rHwctAg)

The additional `Run:Script` you see is added by `VScode` when you have `start:debug` defined in the scripts in your `package.json`.

In already existing projects, to share configs, committing your `VScode` folder is the only option and for new projects, **best** approach to *share the configurations* would be to have your own boilerplate creator with all the required configs added.

Create a wrapper around `create-react-app` to spawn the application boilerplate or your own custom `webpack` boilerplate with all the **configurations** needed ( the one I'd created with redux setup: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mytidbit-react-redux-app ), and have the configs added to `.gitignore` like below.

```
#IDE
.vscode/*
!.vscode/launch.json
```

When your team uses this boilerplate creator to spawn/start a project from scratch, they all will have `uniform configs` as you wanted. so the entire team is in sync. Only issue would be cross-platform compatibility with respect to LF/CRLF EOL etc.

with `start:debug` in the `package.json` scripts and your custom config. `VScode` adds that `Run-Script`

[image]

After removing `start:debug` from the `package.json` scripts, delete `vscode/launch.json` and recreate/add. launch config below

[image]

Comment: I can definitely add the `.vscode` folder but as you can see from the screenshot that `Run-Script ...` is not part of the config. VS Code generated that somehow. I want that config not the one I wrote myself as shown in the screenshot.